# syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I don't know what's wrong with my code. it says on line 11 before the $sqlUPDATEUsername. I'm doing the change username and password thing.

```
$errorEmessage = '&nbsp';
        $NEWusername = $_POST['Nusername'];
        $CONusername = $_POST['Conusername'];
        $NEWpassword = $_POST['Npassword'];
        $CONpassword = $_POST['Conpassword'];

        $sqlUPDATEUsername = "UPDATE user_accounts SET USERNAME = '$NEWusername' WHERE EMPOYEE_ID = $_SESSION['ID']";
        $sqlCheckUsername = "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE userID('EMPOYEE_ID') = $_SESSION['ID']";
        $RunSqlCU = mysql_query($sqlCheckUsername);
        $row =  mysql_fetch_array($RunSqlCU);
```

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with your code. For starters, you really shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They've been deprecated for over 2 years now and leave you wide open SQL injection. Another problem is that you put variables inside single quotes. This means it will take the variable as literal text instead of using the value of the variable. Also, `userID('EMPOYEE_ID')`? I'm fairly sure this isn't a valid column name inside mysql.

Comment: can you teach me how? what should I use?

Comment: I've already fixed the EMPOYEE_ID part

Answer (score -1):

you need to sanitize user input.
 Whenever you embed a string within foreign code, you must escape it, according to the rules of that language. For example, if you embed a string in some SQL targeting MySql, you must escape the string with MySql's function for this purpose `(mysql_real_escape_string)`.

use

```
$NEWusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nusername']);
```

Another example is HTML: If you embed strings within HTML markup, you must escape it with `htmlspecialchars`. This means that every single echo or print statement should use `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: 1) Don't use answers that **don't answer the question**! Use comments instead! 2) Don't advise others to use functions for something that won't help them at all.

Comment: how can I use the my sql_real_escape_string?

Comment: `$NEWusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nusername']);`

Comment: what's the function of the escape string?